# Thread freezes the UI when using a while loop inside Run() method of Runnable object

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to start a thread to perform a piece of code inside a while loop. The problem is that the UI hangs and the progress dialog stops immediately after being shown. when removing the handler object it runs fine, but no changes happen to the UI of course. What is the problem?

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        mTextOutput.setText(mRepeatedText);
    }
};
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Text Repeater");
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("We're generating your text...");
    mProgressDialog.show();
    Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mRepeatedText = StringUtils.repeat(mText, mNumberOfIterations);
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }

    };
    mThread = new Thread(mRunnable);
    mThread.start();
```

StringUtils class

```
public class StringUtils {

public static String repeat(String text, int numberOfIterations){
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(text.length()*numberOfIterations);
    while(numberOfIterations-- > 0){
            buffer.append(text);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Will you please listen and see how exactly run a thread, off the main thread so that UI never blocks or never skips any frames https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfQE1ayCzf8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line of code:

```
        mTextOutput.setText(mRepeatedText);
```

When using a huge number of iterations, for example a 100,000 times. This makes a 100,000 copy of my entered word, sentence or whatever. And it takes time to load all that in the textview.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the return statement in the method repeat in the StringUtils class is not in the right place. This is probably what you are looking for:

```
public class StringUtils {
    public static String repeat(String text, int numberOfIterations) {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(text.length()*numberOfIterations);
        while(numberOfIterations-- > 0){
            buffer.append(text);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. That was an editing mistake, it's alright in the actual code.